# Storing a js cookie for a stylesheet switcher

Tags: javascript, css, cookies

I am having some issues with a website that allows multiple text sizes. I have a script in place that allows the switching and all works great but it isn't storing the function as a cookie so if the user goes to another page the text-size defaults.

I'm not very proficient with javascript, don't have a clue about cookies - wondering if anyone could help me out.

Thanks in advance.

This is my script:

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype) {
    if (filetype == "js") { //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref = document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    } else if (filetype == "css") { //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref = document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref != "undefined") document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

function removejscssfile(filename, filetype) {
    var targetelement = (filetype == "js") ? "script" : (filetype == "css") ? "link" : "none" //determine element type to create nodelist from
    var targetattr = (filetype == "js") ? "src" : (filetype == "css") ? "href" : "none" //determine corresponding attribute to test for
    var allsuspects = document.getElementsByTagName(targetelement)
    for (var i = allsuspects.length; i >= 0; i--) { //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
        if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr) != null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr).indexOf(filename) != -1) allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]) //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()
    }
}
```

Buttons code:

```
<a onClick="removejscssfile('/css/med-font.css', '/css/lrg-font.css', 'css');" href="javascript:loadjscssfile('/css/sml-font.css','css')" id="sml">A</a>
<a onClick="removejscssfile('/css/sml-font.css', '/css/lrg-font.css', 'css');" href="javascript:loadjscssfile('/css/med-font.css','css')" id="med">A</a>
<a onClick="removejscssfile('/css/med-font.css', '/css/sml-font.css', 'css');" href="javascript:loadjscssfile('/css/lrg-font.css','css')" id="lrg">A</a>
```

Comment: Are you developing locally in Chrome? Chrome doesn't (or didn't) support cookies created locally for whatever reason. Try a different browser and see if that is the issue

Comment: why not just storing the needed parameters as cookies? Did I get it right, you want to store the full javascript code in a cookie?

Comment: I'll be honest in saying I don't have a clue about javascript cookies... Basically I have three buttons, when the user clicks one this calls the function to remove the old stylesheet and apply the new one. I'll add my buttons code now. I need to be able to store whatever stylesheet has been chosen throughout the users visit.

Answer (score 3):

This page saves the filename of the last stylesheet selected and saves it to a cookie. When loaded, the page checks to see of the cookie exists and changes stylesheet accordingly.

The content is contained in a wrapper so that there's no apparent change in the browser content as the style is changed on load and the noscript tags are there to ensure that people without javascript enabled can still see the page.

Credit to w3schools for the cookie code and also this SO answer from Sameera Thilakasiri: [adding / removing css Files using JQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877056/adding-removing-css-files-using-jquery) (although I've stuck to native js here)

Caveat: not tested in all browsers and the script should probably be held off-page and started once the page has been fully loaded.

Hope this helps!

```
<html>
<head>
    <link id="docStyleSheets" rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<noscript>
    <div id="divContentWrapper" style="display: none">
</noscript>
<ul id="ulCssChanges">
    <li><a href="#small" onclick="setFontSize('small.css');return false;")>Small</a></li>
    <li><a href="#medium" onclick="setFontSize('medium.css');return false;")>Medium</a></li>
    <li><a href="#large" onclick="setFontSize('large.css');return false;")>Large</a></li>
</ul>
<noscript>
    </div>
</noscript>

<script>
    var Cookies = {
        SetCookie: function (c_name, value, exdays) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
        },

        GetCookie: function (c_name) {
            var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
                x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
                x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                if (x == c_name) {
                    return unescape(y);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (Cookies.GetCookie("fontSize") != "") {
        setFontSize(Cookies.GetCookie("fontSize"));
        if (document.getElementById("divContentWrapper") != null) { document.getElementById("divContentWrapper").style.display = "block"; }
    }

    function setFontSize(styleSheetName) {
        document.getElementById("docStyleSheets").href = styleSheetName;
        Cookies.SetCookie("fontSize", styleSheetName, 60);
        return false;
    }    
</script>
```